TypeScript type hinting similar to `document.createElement`
I am trying to create similar createElement method of my own custom DOM (with custom nodes) for my project, which takes nodeName as argument and returns an instance of corresponding Node.
import { Node } from "./tree";

export class DOM
{
    private defs: Record<string, new () => Node>;

    constructor(nodeDefs: Record<string, new () => Node>)
    {
        for (const [nodeName, NodePrototype] of Object.entries(nodeDefs))
            this.defs[nodeName] = NodePrototype;
    }

    create(nodeName: keyof typeof this.defs)
    {
        const newNode = new this.defs[nodeName]();
        newNode.name = nodeName;

        return newNode;
    }
}

The code works fine but I don't get handy hints of which node names are available and the return type is always just Node, not the exact type of node I am creating.
How should I change the code above to make hints work properly?
const dom = new DOM({
    paragraph: Paragraph,
    text: Text
});

const myP = dom.create('paragraph'); // Correct type hints here!


Let's make your DOM class and create method become generic:
type InstanceTypeOf<T> = T extends new () => infer I ? I : never; // get type from a constructor

export class DOM<T extends Record<string, new () => Node>> { // Genneric T, infer constructor param
  private readonly defs: T = {} as T;

  constructor(nodeDefs: T) {
    for (const [nodeName, NodePrototype] of Object.entries(nodeDefs) as Array<[keyof T, T[string]]>) { // fix typing error
      this.defs[nodeName] = NodePrototype;
    }
  }

  create<K extends Extract<keyof T, string>>(nodeName: K) { // generic, infer by nodeName type
    const newNode = new this.defs[nodeName]();
    newNode.name = nodeName;

    return newNode as InstanceTypeOf<T[K]>; // casting
  }
}

const dom = new DOM({
  paragraph: Paragraph,
  text: Text,
});

const p = dom.create('paragraph');
//    ?^ const p: Paragraph


